# I am facing a Tkinter problem with grid management; the columnspan is not working as I expect

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, columnspan

I am writing a simple playlist downloader (with pytube) and i want to improve myself on Tkinter so i decided to use it to build an interface. However i have some issues with grid management and how to deal with different size on the same column but differents rows.

Here are intersting part of my code :

Functions to place a widget:

```
    def initial_configure_widgets(self,
                                  widget: Union[Entry, Label, Progressbar, Button],
                                  parameters: Dict[str, Any],
                                  use_place_method: bool = False) -> None:
        if (use_place_method):
            widget.place(**parameters)
        else:
            widget.grid(**parameters)
```

```
def format_widget_parameters(row: int,
                             column: int,
                             padx: Tuple[int, int],
                             pady: Tuple[int, int],
                             sticky: str,
                             columnspan: int = 1) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    parameters = {
        "row": row,
        "column": column,
        "padx": padx,
        "pady": pady,
        "sticky": sticky,
        "columnspan": columnspan
    }
    return parameters
```

```
    def configure_grid(self,
                       is_row: List[bool] = [True],
                       index: List[int] = [0],
                       weight: List[int] = [0]) -> None:

        if len(is_row) != len(index) != len(weight):
            raise ValueError("All three lists must have the same length.")

        for i in range(len(is_row)):
            if is_row[i]:
                self.root.grid_rowconfigure(index[i], weight=weight[i])
            else:
                self.root.grid_columnconfigure(index[i], weight=weight[i])
```

And how i use them:

```
    application.initial_configure_widgets(
        download_label, format_widget_parameters(0, 2, (0, 0), (20, 10), "s"))
    application.initial_configure_widgets(
        download_entry, format_widget_parameters(1, 2, (0, 0), (10, 0), "new"))
    application.initial_configure_widgets(
        playlist_button, format_widget_parameters(1, 0, (10, 0), (5, 0), "ew"))
    application.initial_configure_widgets(
        audio_button, format_widget_parameters(1, 1, (0, 10), (5, 0), "ew"))
    application.initial_configure_widgets(
        download_button, format_widget_parameters(2, 2, (0, 0), (5, 0), ""))
    application.initial_configure_widgets(
        download_progressbar, format_widget_parameters(3, 2, (0, padx_west_init), (30, 0), "new"))
    application.initial_configure_widgets(
        folder_button, format_widget_parameters(4, 0, (10, 0), (40, 0), "ew"))
    application.initial_configure_widgets(
        error_canvas, format_widget_parameters(5, 0, (50, 50), (20, 0), "new", 3))
    application.initial_configure_widgets(
        error_label, {'relx': 0, 'rely': 0.5, 'anchor': 'center'}, True)
    application.initial_configure_widgets(
        name_label, format_widget_parameters(6, 0, (0, 0), (0, 0), "new", 3))
    application.initial_configure_widgets(
        name_entry, format_widget_parameters(6, 1, (20, 0), (0, 0), "n", 2))
```

It worked correctly when i didn't place name_label and name_entry but after placing them it doesn't work anymore. My text in name_label is wide so i need to increase the columspan to 3 to avoid changing the size of widget on previous row. But by increasing the columnspan to 3 name_label enters the column 2 that has a width of 1 so it become centered (and has a place that change when changing the size of the window) and no longer stick to the west part of the window.
I want to know if there is a way to achieve what i want.
Thanks a lot

Here are some photos:
[Here we can see with columnspan 3 that the text at the bottom is not stick to the west part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY28o.png)

[And here it's what happen when i keep columnspan of 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWO2r.png)

Comment: Please try to post a single block of code that is a [mcve].

Comment: oh sorry, but how here can i give such example ? I mean the rest of the code to run is a bit long and are mostly useless to understand the problem i think (it is mostly class and widget creation) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want `name_label` to stick to the west, then set `sticky` option to `"w"` instead of `"new"`:

```py
    application.initial_configure_widgets(
        name_label, format_widget_parameters(6, 0, (0, 0), (0, 0), "w", 3))
```